# Entries not sorted by date

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

I noticed some issues looking at my [new developer story](https://stackoverflow.com/story/matteocrippa) page, as you can notice in this screenshot some entries are not well sorted in the flow.

[image: developer story bug screenshot]

E.g. as you can notice first box is referred to 2014, next three to 2008 and then again to 2014. Other one below are referred to 2015 too.

So it seems that is not sorting entries in the expected manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this! We've pushed a fix so that story items are being sorted by start date in the event that they have the same end date :). We're currently looking into more solutions to improve the overall ordering of the timeline.